# How to add min value for a field in custom Module system.xml file?

Tags: module, magento-2.1

I want to add minimum value attribute for a admin interface field in my custom module. Can anyone suggest me how I can add min attribute in field? Here is my **system.xml** code:

```
<field id="uspsintexpress" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
<label>USPS Int'l Express Days</label>
</field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got Solution for my Question. Here is solution **system.xml** code:

```
<field id="uspsintexpress" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
<label>USPS Int'l Express Days</label>
<validate>validate-greater-than-zero</validate>
</field>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

You can add minimum value validation by `backend_model`, for example.

```
<field id="base_url" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Base URL</label>
    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Baseurl</backend_model>
    <comment>Specify URL or {{base_url}} placeholder.</comment>
</field>
```

Then you can find the `beforeSave` method at **\m9agento210\vendor\magento\module-config\Model\Config\Backend\Baseurl.php**

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    $value = $this->getValue();
    try {

       // You can write some validation here.

    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {

        throw $error;
    }
}
```

This is an example, you can implement this in your custom module.

**Option 2**

```
        <field id="custom_email" translate="label comment" sortOrder="0" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>Enter Email Id</label>
            <validate>validate-email</validate>
        </field>
```

Some Important validation classes are

```
'validate-no-html-tags'         => 'HTML tags are not allowed'
'validate-select'               => 'Please select an option.'
'required-entry'                => 'This is a required field.'
'validate-number'               => 'Please enter a valid number in this field.'
'validate-digits'               => 'Please use numbers only in this field. Please avoid spaces or other characters such as dots or commas.'
'validate-date'                 => 'Please enter a valid date.'
'validate-email'                => 'Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.'
'validate-url'                  => 'Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://)'
'validate-not-negative-number'  => 'Please enter a number 0 or greater in this field.'
'validate-zero-or-greater'      => 'Please enter a number 0 or greater in this field.'
'validate-state'                => 'Please select State/Province.'
'validate-cc-number'            => 'Please enter a valid credit card number.'
'validate-data'                 => 'Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Krishna, ie. Okay. is there not any way to validate field directly in system.xml. I just need to add min='1' in my admin XML file ?

Comment: @ Pankaj Sharma,  As of my knowledge, there is no direct config validation like min='1' . You can follow the custom validation options added in the answer.

Comment: Okay fine, if I proceed with option 2. Do you have any idea, how I can create a validation method for my requirement? value should be grater then 0. Remember I am creating a custom model.

Comment: You can simple go with option one by creating custom validation and return response. Please check the core validation once I added in the answer. This may be the quick approach.