# How to add text block in magento 2 custom module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module

I have a admin config page.

Where i have successfully listed my module.

I want to add a text block with procedures to follow. What is the tag that i should use in system.xml in order to use a text block.

I dont want to display it using comment tag since the content is long and it looks cluttered. Also, Is there a option to Link a text in the custom module to an external website like

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for comment ?. 
If so, then you can use comment tag in your system.xml file.

```
<field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>Display Text</label>
    <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
</field>
```

Comment: No I dont want a comment. I want to list a few STEPS(procedures) in my custom module. Also is there a way to link a text to another website from the custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code can help you. You can also use your text block as a `comment` or `lable` in System.xml

```
<field id="FieldID" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
<label>Field label</label>
<validate>Validation</validate>
<comment>You can add your text block as a comment</comment>
</field>
```

For more detail look [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156690/how-to-add-min-value-for-a-field-in-custom-module-system-xml-file)

Comment: I dont want a comment. I need to add a long paragraph. which doesnt looks good when added as a comment tag